# Rails sanitize tag and background-image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitize

I want use html & css in form.text_area :text

```
 <%= sanitize @post.text , tags: %w(table tr td div p span img), attributes: %w(id class style src) %>
```

But css attr "style" don't work with background-image.

```
<div style="color:red; background-image: url('http://tra-ta-ta.com/1.jpg')">
text 
</div>
```

Image don't work. How I can use background-image?

Problem in sanitize.rb

```
def sanitize_css(style) # disallow urls style = style.to_s.gsub(/url\s*\(\s*[^\s)]+?\s*\)\s*/, ' ')
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this CSS, other than that it would be cleaner to put it in an external file rather than inline with the HTML.  Is the URL for the image correct?  Can you put together a jsfiddle?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just use raw without sanitize

Comment: That's a very bad idea for handling user input and should be avoided at any cost.

Answer (score 0):

URL strings "url(...)" in style attribute are force replaced with " " by `HTML::WhiteListSanitizer`, the default sanitizer.  You can implement your own sanitizer, and let Rails use it by editing config/application.rb.

```
config.action_view.white_list_sanitizer = MySpecialSanitizer.new
```

Check following files from ActionPack for more info:

- `actionpack-x.x.x/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb`
- `actionpack-x.x.x/lib/action_controller/vendor/html-scanner/html/sanitizer.rb`

Comment: How I can allow use url(...) just for one field?

  <%= sanitize @post.text , tags: %w(strong em b i p code pre tt samp kbd var sub
      sup dfn cite big small address hr br div span h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 ul ol li dl dt dd abbr
      acronym a img blockquote del ins div img), attributes: %w(id class style src) %>

Comment: `def sanitize_css(style)
      # disallow urls
      style = style.to_s.gsub(/url\s*\(\s*[^\s)]+?\s*\)\s*/, ' ')`

This is it. In actionpack sanitizer.rb  How I cann allow url and '' for one field?